# differentiating formula

Tags: calculus, derivatives, mathematical-physics, implicit-differentiation

> A particle’s motion is described by the following equation: $x = A \cos \cos (ωt)$ . The probability that the particle can be found
> between position $x$ and $x + dx$ is $dp$ $p$ What is the expression for $\frac{dp}{dx}$?

I have a value given.

$$x=A \cos \cos (ωt)$$

The equation was looking weird for me. That's why I thought that, that's why I thought that is $cos^2$. And, the question is saying that $dp=x+dx$, What is the expression for $\frac{dp}{dx}$?

$$x=A\cos\cos(\omega t)$$
$$dx=A\omega \sin \sin(\omega t)$$
$$\frac{dp}{dx}=\frac{x+dx}{dx}=\frac{A\cos\cos(\omega t)+A\omega \sin sin(\omega t)}{A\omega \sin \sin (\omega t)}=\frac{A(\cos^2(\omega t)+\omega \sin^2(\omega t)}{A \omega \sin^2(\omega t)}$$

What the next expression should look like? I think I am doing something wrong with differentiation.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Sorry! I had used as much as I know... I don't think that I left anything..

Comment: I suggest that you use `\cos` and `\sin` to get $\cos$ and $\sin$ respectively.

Comment: Sorry but your question is not clear. I think you should edit it or close it. What is the problem that you are trying to solve? $\cos^2$ of what? There also seem to be some mistakes for example in the computation of $dx$. Maybe try to use google translate to write better english sentences. I don't speak english myself, but some of your sentences are hard to read.

Comment: @NicolasSchmid I added the main question.

Comment: Are you sure the question is asking to compute $\frac{dp}{dt}$ and not $\frac{dp}{dx}?$ The way I understand it p is a probability of finding the particle at a position x at a random time. It shouldn't be something that depends on time.

Comment: @NicolasSchmid I am really sorry. I wrote the question wrong... While I was formatting math texts. Unfortunately, I removed $dx$ and wrote $dt$.. I am sorry.. Could you please work on your answer again?

Comment: Because the asker seems to be confused about this, I'll clear some things up. If $T$ is a mapping (function, operator, etc) then $T^2$ *almost always* means $T\circ T$, **except** for circular and hyperbolic functions, i.e $\sin^2 x$ means $(\sin x)^2$, and not $\sin(\sin x)$. This exception is due to the fact that compositions of these functions appear very rarely in practice.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are trying to solve the following problem:

The position of a particle is given by the formula : $x = A cos^2(wt)$ and we want to find the derivative with respect to the position of $p(x)$ which is the probability density of finding a particle at a certain position.

As explained [here](https://cmm.cit.nih.gov/intro_simulation/node4.html), the probability that the oscillating particle is at a given value of x is simply the fraction of time that it spends there, which is inversely proportional to its velocity in this point. The particle must stop completely (for a moment) before reversing its direction, and so it spends the most time where the spring is either fully compressed or fully extended. It spends the least time where its velocity is greatest i.e., where the spring is at its equilibrium length.

$v(t)=\frac{dx(t)}{dt} = -2Acos(wt)sin(wt)w = -Asin(2wt)w$

$p(x)$ is proportional to $\frac{1}{v(t)}$ at $t=\frac{1}{w} \arccos{\sqrt \frac{x}{A}}$

Then you can normalise $p(x)$ and take the derivative of this expression to find $\frac{dp}{dx}$. But in my opinion taking the derivative of $p$ with respect to time doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Sorry! You researched a lot to write the answer. But, for my mistake you have to work again. That's why I am really Sorry!